# return enabled inputs ids and create variables from them in jquery

Tags: jquery, each

My goal is to create variables from enabled input ID's and create selector variables from them.

This is example of HTML:

```
<input type="number" class="numberInput" id="input1"/> 
<input type="number" class="numberInput" id="input2" disabled/> <!-- Do not return this id -->
<input type="number" class="numberInput" id="input3"/>
<input type="number" class="numberInput" id="input4"/>
<input type="number" class="numberInput" id="input5" disabled/> <!-- Do not return this id -->
```

So the function should return only `#input1`, `#input3` and `#input4`.
I did following:

```
$(".numberInput:enabled").each(function(){
      var enabledInputId = this.id;    
    });
```

Which does the trick, but I want to make variables from returned ID.

Something like:

```
var value1 = $("#" + returnedId); //index 0 -- should return #input1
var value2 = $("#" + returnedId); //index 1 -- should return #input3
var value3 = $("#" + returnedId); //index 2 -- should return #input4
```

**NOTE:** Disabled and enabled inputs will be changed on different events, so I want only make variables which are enabled at this moment.

Comment: can you clarify what you meant by "but I want to make variables from returned ID" !!

Comment: Sure, the each function mentioned in question returns ids of enabled inputs and I want make variables from them. So the new vars will be direct selector on them. return id - input1 and create selector $("#input1");

Comment: do you really need to create seperate variables for all of them? Can't you just save them in an array? You already have your desired value so it won't be tough.!

Comment: Well, but the new variable will actually select different ID. For example: return input1 id -> add option with value == id in <select> with this id.The only thing I dont know how to select each of returned ID, using [0] or something like this.

Comment: maybe now i understand what you want to with those. you have the id in `.each` function but you are not able to use them selector but you want to do this?

Comment: Yes, how to make vars from them? I know only how to append them or alert. Another example may be: how to return .val() of these ids and then multiply first by 2, second by one... or how to select first ( index 0) second (index 1) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var enabledIds = [];
var i = 0;
$(".numberInput:enabled").each(function(){
      enabledIds[i] = '#'+this.id;      
      console.log(enabledIds[i]);
      var value = $(enabledIds[i]).val();
      console.log(value);
      i++;
    });
```

Here is a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4kh5neja/2/)

Comment: It was just an example with these .val()'s. But I still dont get how to select first input ID returned by each function. Something like: this.id[0] ?

Comment: @t4d_ look what i have done here. I have an `enabledIds` array in which i have saved all `selectors` meaning id of enabled input that's why i didn't use return statement plus I can then select first input as `$(enabledIds[0])` 2nd  enabled input as `$(enabledIds[1])` so on...

Comment: welcome...let me know if you have any more query regarding this question :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm just learning :) Let me ask one more thing
If we had three divs containing text, ex.: 1. div = "I'm first" 2. div = "I'm second" and 3.div = "I'm third". How can I replace these texts using .text() and .each() ? One button click will change these texts to {(1), (2), (3)}. and another button will change it back?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117371/discussion-between-asif-rahaman-and-t4d).